# JAXB one Marshaller instance and Unmarshaller instance per application

Tags: java, jaxb

I have web application, where I have classes generated from xsd schema.
I am creating one Marshaller instance and one Unmarshaller instance as static final fields on application startup.

I want to know whether this is good practice, or it is better to create independent instances per need ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Caching `Marschaller` and `Unmarshaller` is not a good idea. Cache the `JAXBContext` instead.

`JAXBContext` may be reused to create marshallers and unmarshallers.

`Marshaller` and `Unmarshaller` instances are NOT (necessarily) thread-safe or reusable.

I'll look for the references and update the answer.

Here's the [reference](https://jaxb.java.net/guide/Performance_and_thread_safety.html):

> The JAXBContext class is thread safe, but the Marshaller,
>   Unmarshaller, and Validator classes are not thread safe.

Related answer:

[JAXB creating context and marshallers cost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400422/jaxb-creating-context-and-marshallers-cost)

Comment: Marshaller and Unmarshaller are reusable

Comment: @Rustam Citation needed.

Comment: From your first link: "Different threads may reuse one Unmarshaller instance, as long as you don't use one instance from two threads at the same time."