# List of available marshalling-unmarshalling frameworks for java

Tags: java, xml, apache, marshalling, unmarshalling

Please provide me a list of marshalling-unmarshalling java frameworks which are compatible with JDK 1.4. Im currently trying to use castor, but not going well. So i want to try other options.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

We've been using JAXB.  Some other options are discussed here: [What to use instead of XMLBeans now that it has been retired?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27727546/what-to-use-instead-of-xmlbeans-now-that-it-has-been-retired) (I'm assuming you are looking for xml marshaling/unmarshaling from the tags for this post)

Comment: Yes, JAXB is the standard. But we cant use it snce we are constrained by JDK 1.4

Comment: @user1994694 You can use it. It was previously a separate download in the JAX-WS package, if you can find it.