# Spring batch Jaxb2Marshaller share JAXBContext

Tags: jaxb, spring-batch

I'm using the StaxEventItemReader to unmarshal xml. As in my import process there can be many files of the same type(I use a custom partitioner to read 1 file per thread), I'm getting a lot of:

> o.s.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller             : Creating JAXBContext with
>   classes to be bound

I read on https://stackoverflow.com/a/7400735/384984 that the JAXBContext is thread safe. So it seems like that part could be improved and use only 1 instance for that.

I'm using this reader:

```
public class MultiResourceXmlImportReader<T> extends MultiResourceItemReader<T> {

    public MultiResourceXmlImportReader(FileTypeEnum fileType, Resource... resources)  {
        super();
        setResources(resources);
        setDelegate(new XmlImportReader(fileType.getRootElementName(), fileType.getXmlEntityClass()));
    }
}
```

with this ResourceAwareItemReaderItemStream:

```
public class XmlImportReader<T> extends StaxEventItemReader<T> {

    public XmlImportReader(String rootElementName, Class<T> modelClass) {
        setFragmentRootElementName(rootElementName);

        Jaxb2Marshaller itemMarshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        itemMarshaller.setClassesToBeBound(modelClass);
        setUnmarshaller(itemMarshaller);
    }

    public XmlImportReader(String rootElementName, Class<T> modelClass, Resource resource) {
        this(rootElementName, modelClass);
        setResource(resource);
    }

}
```

Is there anyway to use just 1 instace of a JAXBContext?

Comment: The `StaxEventItemReader` is not threadsafe.  I would just recommend making it `step` scoped.

Comment: My question is if the JAXBContext can be set and shared between multiple StaxEventItemReader