# Jackson not capitalizing XML elements

Tags: java, xml, jackson

Let's say I have following XML model:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "person",
        "user"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "CUSTOMER")
public class CUSTOMER {
    @XmlElement(name = "PERSON", required = true)
    protected CUSTOMER.PERSON person;
    @XmlElement(name = "USER", required = true)
    protected CUSTOMER.USER user;
 ....
 ....
```

If I rename class following conventions as:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "person",
        "user"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "CUSTOMER")
public class Customer {
....
```

And both elements like:

```
    @XmlElement(name = "PERSON", required = true)
    protected CUSTOMER.PERSON person;
    @XmlElement(name = "USER", required = true)
    protected CUSTOMER.USER user;
    ....
```

The XML from

```
new XmlMapper().writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(customer))
```

looks like this:

```
<Customer>
  <id>id</id>
  ...
  <person>
    <id>id</id>
    ...
  </person>
  <user>
    <id>id</id>
    ...
  </user>
</Customer>
```

But I want it to look like this:

```
<CUSTOMER>
  <id>id</id>
  ...
  <PERSON>
    <id>id</id>
    ...
  </PERSON>
  <USER>
    <id>id</id>
    ...
  </USER>
</CUSTOMER>
```

Am I doing something wrong?
I saw that I can use @JsonProperty and it works, but only for the fields and I feel wrong using **Json**Property on an XML element.
Is it okay for my model classes to be named CUSTOMER, PERSON, USER or should I rename them, and if its better to rename them should I use JsonProperty? What about the RootElement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Jackson is not parsing the JAXB annotations. To fix it, you could use an annotation introspector such as [`JaxbAnnotationIntrospector`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-modules-base/javadoc/jaxb/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jaxb/JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.html):

```java
XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector(mapper.getTypeFactory()));

String xml = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(costumer);
```

Also check the [`JaxbAnnotationIntrospector`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-modules-base/javadoc/jaxb/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jaxb/JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.html) documentation, as there are some limitations.

---

If, for some reason, you intend to use JAXB directly, as you mentioned in the comments, you would have something like:

```java
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
marshaller.marshal(customer, writer);

String xml = writer.toString();
```

Just bear in mind the `JAXBContext` should be created once and then reused, as pointed out in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7400735/1426227).

Comment: This works, is there a XmlMapper equivalent in JAXB I can use instead of retrofitting XmlMapper?

Comment: @D.Tomov I'm not sure I'm following your comment. Why don't you use JAXB directly then?

Comment: I am looking for a way to use these objects with RestTemplate. Is there a JAXB way of making Objects to String. I am not familiar with JAXB. This is an generated class.

Comment: @D.Tomov I've updated my answer with an example on how to use JAXB, but I would need more context to give you a more elaborated answer. You always can [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and provide further details on how you are using `RestTemplate`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer If I could upload twice I would.